# Extract string using `rm_between` function

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to extract strings using `rm_between` function from the `library(qdapRegex)`
I need to extract the string between the second "|" and the word "_HUMAN".
I cant figure out how to select the second "|" and not the first.

```
example <- c("sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN", "sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN") 
prots <- rm_between(example, '|', 'HUMAN', extract=TRUE)
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `rm_between(example, '|', 'HUMAN', extract=TRUE)` command, the `|` is used to match the leftmost `|` and  `HUMAN` is used to match the left most `HUMAN` right after.

Note the default value for the `FIXED` argument is `TRUE`, so `|` and `HUMAN` are treated as literal chars.

You need to make the pattern a regex pattern, by setting `fixed=FALSE`. However, the `^(?:[^|]*\|){2}` as the `left` argument regex will not work because the `qdap` package creates an ICU regex with lookarounds (since you use `extract=TRUE` that sets `include.markers` to `FALSE`), which is `(?<=^(?:[^|]*\|){2}).*?(?=HUMAN)`.

As a workaround, you could use a *constrained-width* lookbehind, by replacing `*` with a limiting quantifier with a reasonably large `max` parameter. Say, if you do not expect more than a 1000 chars between each pipe, you may use `{0,1000}`:

```
rm_between(example, '^(?:[^|]{0,1000}\\|){2}', '_HUMAN', extract=TRUE, fixed=FALSE)
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "EIFCL"
# 
#    [[2]]
#    [1] "EIF3C"
```

However, you really should think of using simpler approaches, like those described in other answers. Here is another variation with `sub`:

```
sub("^(?:[^|]*\\|){2}(.*?)_HUMAN.*", "\\1", example)
# => [1] "EIFCL" "EIF3C"
```

**Details**

- `^` - startof strig
- `(?:[^|]*\\|){2}` - two occurrences of any 0 or more non-pipe chars followed with a pipe char (so, matching up to and including the second `|`)
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `_HUMAN.*` - `_HUMAN` and the rest of the string.

`\1` keeps only Group 1  value in the result.

A `stringr` variation:

```
stringr::str_match(example, "^(?:[^|]*\\|){2}(.*?)_HUMAN")[,2]
# => [1] "EIFCL" "EIF3C"
```

With `str_match`, the captures can  be accessed easily, we do it with `[,2]` to get Group 1 value.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using regmatches, regexpr and using perl=TRUE to make use of `\K`

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\K[^|_]+(?=_HUMAN)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rmkmkc/1)

For example

```
regmatches(example, regexpr("^(?:[^|]*\\|){2}\\K[^|_]+(?=_HUMAN)", example, perl=TRUE))
```

Output

```
[1] "EIFCL" "EIF3C"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular `gsub`:

```
example <- c("sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN", "sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN") 

gsub(".*?\\|.*?\\|(.*?)_HUMAN", "\\1", example)
#> [1] "EIFCL" "EIF3C"
```

The part `(.*?)` is replaced by itself as the replacement contains the back-reference `\\1`.

If you absolutely prefer `qdapRegex` you can try:

```
rm_between(example, '.{0,100}\\|.{0,100}\\|', '_HUMAN', fixed = FALSE, extract = TRUE)
```

The reason why we have to use `.{0,100}` instead of `.*?` is that the underlying `stringi` needs a mamixmum length for the look-behind pattern (i.e. the `left` argument in `rm_between`).

Answer (score 1):

this is not exactly what you asked for, but you can achieve the result with base R:

```
sub("^.*\\|([^\\|]+)_HUMAN.*$", "\\1", example)
```

This solution is an application of regular expression.
`"^.*\\|([^\\|]+)_HUMAN.*$"` matches the entire character string.
`\\1` matches whatever was matched inside the first parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying that you could easily just use `sapply()/strsplit()`:

```
example <- c("sp|B5ME19|EIFCL_HUMAN", "sp|Q99613|EIF3C_HUMAN")
unlist(sapply(strsplit(example, "|", fixed = T), 
              function(item) strsplit(item[3], "_HUMAN", fixed = T)))
# [1] "EIFCL" "EIF3C"
```

It just splits on `|` in the first list and on `_HUMAN` on every third element within that list.